# ComboBox selection in DataGrid gets reset when clicking on another column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have a DataGrid with two Columns. One is a DataGridTextColumn the other is a DataGridComboBoxColumn. Both are bound to property and are editable. So when I change the selection of the ComboBox and then click at some white space the cell shows the correct selection. But if I click at the TextColumn beside it the ComboBox exits editing mode and resets the selection to whatever was selected before.

Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you post the WPF code for the DataGridComboBoxColumn?  Might be able to help if we can see that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted your code I'm making assumptions as to what your problem is.

1. You need to specify `TwoWay` mode in your `DataGrid`.
2. You need to Bind the property `SelectedValueBinding` in your `DataGridComboBoxColumn`

   ```
   <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="DropDownComboBox" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=FieldFromData}" Header="SomeName" IsReadOnly="False"/>
   ```

In the code define the combobox contents.

```
 DropDownComboBox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ValuesPossible));
```

If you don't have the Binding set to the property in the data set you are displaying, it will just be a drop down that doesn't change the value of the data anywhere.  The above example takes and populates the combobox with the values that could be selected and selects what is contained in the data set for the FieldFromData.

You will also need to bind the DataGrid in two way mode to allow the selected value to change the field.

```
<DataGrid ..<properties>..   ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility="Visible"  Header="Reason Id"  Width="250">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <ComboBox x:Name="" SelectedValue="{Binding TypeId}" SelectedValuePath="TypeId" DisplayMemberPath="Type"  
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding TypeItems}" ></ComboBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Check your columns DataPropertyName property.
I had a similar issue. The 'Type' was never getting set. Code was getting set twice, but incorrectly on the 2nd time.

Incorrect:

grcLocMill2Code.DataPropertyName = "MillCodeId";

grcLocMill2Code.DataPropertyName = "MillTypeId";

Correct:

grcLocMill2Code.DataPropertyName = "MillCodeId";

grcLocMill2Type.DataPropertyName = "MillTypeId";